# How can i create multiple joomla websites with the same users/passwords?

Tags: joomla

How can i create multiple joomla websites with the same users/passwords
?
if someone creates a user on any of these websites , hes user can be used in all of them , if someone changes password/any data they will be updated on the other websites also.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Joomla has several authentification methods. So if you're able to use a LDAP server or OpenID, you can enable the related plugins - and you'll have all credentials on one server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using 1.5, look at the files in your `plugins/authentication` folder. Basically you create a class which extends the JPlugin class and implement the method with this header:

```
function onAuthenticate( $credentials, $options, &$response );
```

It should return a bool and any extra information can go in the response object. You can do whatever database lookups you need.

So, once you have that set up, what you could do is create a new database which just holds user account details. Your new authentication plugin could then connect to that database to check the password, and perhaps even copy over any updated account information.